# htaccess redirect file requests from specific folder to another hostname

Tags: .htaccess

I need to use a .htaccess file to properly redirect static file requests from a vhost I'm current testing, and its own domain once testing is complete and migration performed to a central domain where static files are stored.

Example request URLs:

```
http://0.0.0.0/fotosctr/foto1.jpg

http://0.0.0.0/~vhost1/fotosctr/foto1.jpg

http://domain1.com/fotosctr/foto1.jpg
```

Should instead request the file at:

```
http://example.com/fotosctr/foto1.jpg
```

How would a htaccess file for this be like?

I've tried some samples like redirecting from one folder to another, but what I'm trying to accomplish doesn't come close.

Comment: I think u are looking for mod proxy. Are you able to alter the apache config? (Gonna post a detailed answer if so)

Comment: Yes I can alter Apache's configuration.

Comment: Is the provided answer working for you? :)

Comment: @Mark I believe it would work, but I took the simpler approach.

Comment: The solution from @anubhava is perfect for your case, I wanted to add an other better scaling solution. :)

Comment: I appreciate it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this redirect rule inside `fotosctr/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks. I only ended up doing a few minor changes to preserve the protocol.

Comment: Yes, thats what I did.

Comment: I used `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}:s on:(s) ` instead of `RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|`

Comment: yes, that would also work.. this is just a bit shorter

Comment: I'm using this to rewrite file requests, any thoughts on why it works and sometimes doesn't ? Its rare but it happens, mostly when I try to refresh without cache.

Comment: This rule should always work as there is only one condition, It could be due to browser caching.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RewriteRule` but I would prefer to use the [`mod_proxy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html). It has a bit better performance overall and also a bit better manageability. (Connection timeouts etc.)

For your case in the `your-site.conf`:

```
ProxyPass "/~vhost1/" "http://example.com/"
ProxyPassReverse "/~vhost1/" "http://example.com/"
ProxyPass "/" "http://example.com/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://example.com/"
```

**Note** that the order is relevant as the `ProxyPass`utilizes the first matching start of the URI.